# Is that the 'path to war' which I am giving wrong? If yes,how do I do a rollback?

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, netbeans, fedora

I have been trying to use the command to rollback the last process of deploying the website which was interrupted due to a network failure.

The generic command that I am using while inside the bin directory of server's SDK *(On Linux)* is :

```
./appcfg.sh rollback /path_to_the_war_directory_that_has_appengine-web.xml
```

Is this the way we do a rollback ? If not please tell me the method.

_(I was asked to make a directory *war* in the project directory and place the WEB-INF folder in that with appengine-web.xml inside it. It may be wrong)_

I am fully convinced that I am making a mistake while  giving the path to my app .

Shot where my *.war* file is there :

[image]

Now the command that I am using is *(while inside the bin directory of the server's SDK)* :

```
./appcfg.sh rollback /home/non-admin/NetbeansProjects/'Personal Site'/web/war
```

The following is the representation of the path to war directory :

[image]

Where am I wrong ? How should I run this command so that I am able to deploy my project once again ?

On running the above command I get this message :

```
Unable to find the webapp directory /home/non-admin/NetbeansProjects/Personal Site/web/war
usage: AppCfg [options] <action> [<app-dir>] [<argument>]
```

*NOTE : I have duplicated the folder WEB-INF. There is still a folder named WEB-INF inside the web directory that contains all other xml files.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that the folder `/home/non-admin/NetbeansProjects/Personal Site/web/war` does not exist. If you look carefully the name of the folder is `NetBeansProjects` (the filesystem in Linux is case-sensitive).

So, you should run instead the command:

```
./appcfg.sh rollback /home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/'Personal Site'/web/war
```

and just to make sure that the directory exists run first

```
ls /home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/'Personal Site'/web/war
```

Comment: currently I am on windows..I will check in few minutes.But are you sure if am doing the right thing. I mean making the _war_ directory and putting it inside the _META-INF_ folder containing _appengine-web.xml_ file ?

Comment: I think you mean a WEB-INF folder inside the war directory. That's what you showed in your question. I recommend you to look the documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig. Also you are missing the web.xml file.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have duplicated the _META-INF_ folder

Comment: You said you duplicated the WEB-INF folder. Also take a look at the project structure of the projects in the demos folder of the sdk.

Comment: I had to duplicate the _META-INF_ folder inside the _war_ folder. Finally got it. Thanks !